# How to handle user input type in java?

Tags: java

If the allowed input in my program is only of type `int` but they user arbitrarily types in a not-allowed type character such as `double` or `char` etc. How do i handle that? I am sure there is so sort of `Throw exception` sort of thing but i am just not sure how it is done. Any suggestions will be appreciated

```
//here is my code
System.out.print("Too " +additionalInfo+ "! Try again: ");
attemptCounter++;
int x= input.nextInt(); // here is where i want the usr to type in their input
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29 says: *Throws: InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range*. Learn exceptions by reading your text book, or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: If you love me so much because I linked to the exceptions tutorial, then you should learn to love Google. Generally, typing "<some subject> java tutorial" in Google directly leads to the java tutorial on <some subject>. Typing "SomeClass java api doc" directly leads to the javadoc of SomeClass. Or you could bookmark the javadoc main page and browse the packages and classes. Learn to become autonomous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to prompt user for input again after an invalid input e.g.

```
    int userInput;
    while(true) {    
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            userInput = input.nextInt();
            break;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException ex ) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Number, Please try again");
        }
    }
```